# Full calendar not rending events in the client

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I'm trying to make a calendar showing all the weekdays and events, without considering what day of the month it is. The dates coming from the database are "random", and in the C# code I get the current week and associate each "random" date with the corresponding day of the current week (so the user doesnt )(public DateTime AssimilarDataAoDiaSemana(string dia, List dts)).

And I have this C# code https://pastebin.com/ipe4t8Pa ,which returns a JSON, for example:

```js
{
    "events":[
     {
         "title": "VIP",
         "start": "2018-03-03 10:00:00",
         "end": "2018-03-03 11:00:00",
         "allDay": false
     },
     {
         "title": "ALMANAQUE DA CACAU",
         "start": "2018-02-25 17:00:00",
         "end": "2018-02-25 18:00:00",
         "allDay": false
     }
    ]
}
```

This is my javascript

```js
function Grade() {
if (VerificarURL("programacao")) {
    var cal = $("#calendario").fullCalendar({
        events: {
            url: "/programacao/calendario",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            color: "white",
            textColor: 'white'
        },
        columnHeaderFormat: "dddd",
        handleWindowResize: true,
        header: false,
        height: "auto",
        defaultView: "agendaWeek",
        editable: false,
        minTime: "06:00",
        maxTime: "24:00",
        displayEventTime: false,
        allDaySlot: false,
        allDayText: false,
        timeFormat: "HH(:mm)",
        slotLabelFormat: "HH:mm",
    });
}
}
```

The problems is: the events are not rendered in the client. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply the format of the JSON you're returning is not compatible with what fullCalendar expects. You need to return just the array of events, without the object wrapped around it. Your event data needs to look like this only:

```
[
     {
         "title": "VIP",
         "start": "2018-03-03 10:00:00",
         "end": "2018-03-03 11:00:00",
         "allDay": false
     },
     {
         "title": "ALMANAQUE DA CACAU",
         "start": "2018-02-25 17:00:00",
         "end": "2018-02-25 18:00:00",
         "allDay": false
     }
]
```

fullCalendar expects the JSON to be an array. If you return an object as per your example, it does not know to look inside it to find the array, and will just assume there are no events.

If you modify your C# code slightly to produce this output instead, it should work nicely.

Comment: The format of the JSON, like you said, was not compatible. But it was not only that. The format of the date is not compatible either. Tested it here and it should actually be "2018-02-25T17:00:00" with the "T" in the middle. Now it works! Thanks!